# Update Swift NSTextfield variable when it's changed

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

How can I write this so that it updates the variable when the user finishes using the field (for Cocoa?). The aim is to allow the user to specify a custom IP address for the TV's location on the network.

```
import Cocoa
import Alamofire

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTextFieldDelegate {

@IBAction func MenuButton(_ sender: NSButtonCell) {
    triggerRemoteControl(irccc: "AAAAAQAAAAEAAABgAw==")
}
@IBAction func ReturnButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
    triggerRemoteControl(irccc: "AAAAAgAAAJcAAAAjAw==")
}
```

…

```
@IBOutlet var IPField: NSTextField!  // [A] Set by the user
```

…

```
func triggerRemoteControl(irccc: String) {
    Alamofire.request(IPField,     // [B] Goes here when it's updated.
                      method: .post,
                      parameters: ["parameter" : "value"],
                      encoding: SOAPEncoding(service: "urn:schemas-sony-com:service:IRCC:1",
                                             action: "X_SendIRCC", IRCCC: irccc)).responseString { response in
                                                print(response)
    }
}


}
```

— UPDATE

I tried declaring a variable:

```
var IPString: String
```

and then (I set the textField's delegate to ViewController, and placed this function inside):

```
override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification){
    let IPString = IPField.stringValue
}
```

Even using the "-> String" and return notation still has it complaining about unused variables. I obviously don't know my Syntax well enough.

Complier also complains about not the ViewController not being initialised.

Comment: If both text fields are in the same controller use Cocoa Bindings

Comment: What is the problem? The trigger, how to get the contents of the text field, setting the variable, which variable or something else? Describe what you want to happen and which part doesn't work.

Comment: Willeke, I'm trying to get the part I commented "[A]" to receive text and set it as a variable usable by "[B]". It is currently nonfunctional. I don't know where to go next.

Comment: I have a NSTextfield, and an outlet in my view controller. I don't know how to take that outlet and feed it into func triggerRemoteControl, replacing IPField. I want the NSTextfield variable to refresh every time a user finishes editing the field. Is this possible?

Comment: You can get the value of `IPField` with one of the value methods/properties of `NSControl`, `NSTextField`s superclass.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not good enough at this yet to do that without help. So I found NSTextDidEndEditing property of the NSTextField's superclass. I don't know how to implement this. Or any of this….

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to override the [func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1428847-controltextdidendediting) function

You should take a look at:

- [object](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification/1414469-object) (property of [obj](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification)) - sometimes you would like to know which object sent you the end editing action.
- [userInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification/1409222-userinfo) (property of [obj](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification)) - contains a [`"NSTextMovement"`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nstext/1540711-movement_codes) key, which allows you to define how the user did end the editing.

`override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification){
    let IPString = IPField.stringValue
}`

Here, you're creating new constant. What you want is to set this value into your class variable, so you should make `IPString = IPField.stringValue`

But it's not quite correct, because `func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification)` could be called from other objects, so first you should check if `obj` notification contain object which send it with guard, for example.

`guard let object = obj.object else {
    return 
}`

Then check if object is your IPField with identity operators

`guard object === IPField else {
    return
}`

And finally you can assign your field value to your `IPString` var

`IPString = object.stringValue`

Hope it will help you. Ohh and one advice from my side, you should use lower camel case naming convention for you variables.

Comment: I tried setting a variable, and then setting the textbox's delegate to the ViewController…. 

I tried defining a variable:

var IPString: String

And then using this: (as you said)
    
    override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification){
        let IPString = IPField.stringValue
    }

And then calling the variable in Alamofire… but it didn't work. Nothing seems to ever work for me.

Errors: Class ViewController has no initialisers. Also complains no matter what I do that I'm not using the result of my function and that I should use an "_".

Comment: Try changing `var IPString: String` to `var ipString: String?` and it warning you about changing name of `let IPString = IPField.stringValue` to `_= IPField.stringValue`, because you're creating here new constant and do not use it anywhere, so there is no point to naming this let. I updated post for you.

Comment: You can tell compiler that this variable will never be nil with `var IPString: String!` and set it for example in viewDidLoad. You can also just set a empty value `var IPString = ""`, but the safest option is to stay with optional String and use _optional binding_.

Comment: This causes a crash, even if the field is filled out.
    
    `override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification){
        if let _ = IPField?.stringValue {
            _ = IPField?.stringValue
        } else {
            let _ = "192.168.0.0"
        }
    }`

Comment: Which line causes a crash? And you're using _optional binding_ in wrong way. It should look like `override func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification){ if let ip = IPField?.stringValue { IPString = ip } else { IPString = "192.168.0.0" } }` probably.

Comment: Well it works perfectly if I remove focus from the textfield element i.e. "didendediting", but if I leave the field blank or don't properly remove focus, the app crashes at the point where Alamofire asks for the value.

Comment: I fixed it! I made a function to check if it's empty. I don't know if this is really that efficient, but it works consistently. `func notNil() -> String{
    
    if IPString == ""{
    IPString = "192.168.0.0"
        return IPString
    } else { return IPString}
    }`